# How can I create a PHP Advanced Search using a simple HTML form with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want for my users to be able to search for multiple criteria from the search form.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="form_search" action="search.php" method="post">
    <input class="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for a property for sell or rent" autocomplete="off">
    <select name="min_val" class="control_option option_select min_val">
        <option selected>Property Type</option>
        <option>Homes for Sale</option>
        <option>Homes to Let</option>
        <option>Student Accomodation</option>
        <option>Commercial</option>
        <option>Land and Sites</option>
        <option>Auctions</option>
        <option>Agricultural</option>
    </select>
    <select name="max_val" class="control_option option_select max_val">
        <option selected>Max Price</option>
        <option>&pound;25,000</option>
        <option>&pound;50,000</option>
        <option>&pound;100,000</option>
        <option>&pound;150,000</option>
        <option>&pound;200,000</option>
        <option>&pound;250,000</option>
        <option>&pound;300,000</option>
        <option>&pound;350,000</option>
        <option>&pound;400,000</option>
        <option>&pound;450,000</option>
        <option>&pound;500,000</option>
        <option>&pound;600,000+</option>
    </select>
    <select name="beds" class="control_option no_bed">
        <option selected>Bedrooms</option>
        <option>1 Bedroom</option>
        <option>2 Bedrooms</option>
        <option>3 Bedrooms</option>
        <option>4 Bedrooms</option>
        <option>4+ Bedrooms</option>
    </select>
    <input class="search_btn" name="search_button" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I can get it to search my database okay, but I am stumped for getting it to search for multiple things at once.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['search'];
$terms = explode(" ", $search);
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE";

foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= " keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}
if ($i == 1)
    $query .= " price BETWEEN 0 AND '%$each%'";

$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        echo "<h1>$title</h1><br />
        $description<br />$price<hr />";
    }
} else {
    echo "<b>Sorry we found no properties matching '$search', please try another term.</b>";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Your `price BETWEEN`... will only work if your for loop is only 1 long. But what is not working with it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @putvande I am trying to create a search function for my website so that users will be able to narrow the results using the pre-set `<select>` in HTML. Can you explain a bit more on the `price BETWEEN`?

Comment: Well, you do the for loop and increment `$i`. Say you loop it three times your `$i` will be 2 (or 3?). Then you get to the part of `price BETWEEN` but your condition `$i == 1` is false so you won't come there.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but would it be possible to include in the one loop rather than separate ones searching for different things. For the one loop I would need it to search for the user's `<input>` and then what they have selected for the drop-down menus.

Comment: "Thanks in advanced" Haha! Advanced search.

Comment: You are using both HTML (`<option selected>`) and XHTML (`<br />`) at the same time. Either use XHTML (`<option selected="selected">`) or HTML (`<br>`), but not both. Also you are using a literal newline inside string literal, which is IMO bad practice. Indentation and end of line type of your code influences the output. I suggest using `\n` instead: `echo "…<br />\n$description…<h1>";`

Answer (score 0):

This is arough idea about how to proceed. there are better way to write this with function.

```
<?php
            $search = $_GET['search'];
        $min_val = $_GET['min_val'];
        $max_val = $_GET['max_val'];
            //$terms = explode(" ", $search);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE"; 
            $init=1;
            if (isset($search) ){
                $query .= (($init==1)?'':' OR ')." keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
                $init=($init==1)?0:$init;   
            }
            if (isset($min_val) ){
                $query .= (($init==1)?'':' OR ')." price BETWEEN $min_val AND '$max_val' ";
                $init=($init==1)?0:$init;   
            }


            $query = mysql_query($query);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if ($numrows > 0 ) {
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $description = $row['description'];
                    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                    $price = $row['price'];
                    $link = $row['link']; 
                    echo "<h1>$title</h1><br />
                    $description<br />$price<hr />";
                }

            } else {
            echo "<b>Sorry we found no properties matching '$search', please try another term.</b>";
            }

            mysql_close();
        ?>
```

Comment: `init==1` should be `$init==1`. `$_GET'min_val']` should be `$_GET['min_val']`, the same with `max_val`. Please read your answers before posting ;)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `init`, however I am receiving a syntax error for `$query .= ((init==1)?'':' OR ')" keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";` just after `((init==1)?`

Comment: @user3154966 `init` is a variable, he typed it wrong. Leave it as `(($init==1)?` and it should work.

Comment: sorry for those typos @AlejandroIván, its dark in here

Comment: @GunnerAziz yeah it happens ;) there's still one typo in the first `if`, cheers!

Comment: I am getting the syntax error for the `?''` the ' ' being the error

Comment: changed that place,just appending that thing. You understand string append right?

Comment: @user3154966 you should learn PHP first if you're going to do more complex things. Those typos are an easy fix if you understand a little PHP. Fyi, `$a = $b == $c ? 1 : 2;` is the same as `if ($b == $c) { $a = 1; } else { $a = 2; }`

Comment: @AlejandroIván, I understand the basis of PHP and can create the simple things, this one just got to me :( basically means more practice then

Comment: @user3154966 exactly! Just keep practicing, this will eventually be kid's play! Good luck!

Comment: Hopefully, At least I can learn from my mistakes. @AlejandroIván I cannot seem to figure out why it is giving me a `parse error: syntax error` I find syntax for languages simple but the syntax for appending this is beating me. Can't get why it's coming up like this.